# Efficient way to manage info-window html code

Tags: javascript, html, string, google-maps-api-3

I have been working on a project based on Google Maps API v3 for over a year now. There has been many, many changes to the information displayed in the info window.

I am looking for a more efficient way to manage the html code other than a string variable. Any ideas?

```
var tabA = "" +
    '<div class="iw_field"><div class="iw_label">NAME</div>'+
    '<div class="iw_data">'+c[i].pName+'</div></div>' +
    '<div class="iw_field"><div class="iw_label">CORPORATION</div>'+
    '<div class="iw_data">'+c[i].corp+'</div></div>' +
    '<div class="iw_field"><div class="iw_label">INDUSTRY</div>'+
    '<div class="iw_data">'+c[i].industry+'</div></div>'+
    "<div style='text-align: center;'>"+
    "<button class='btn btn-info' onclick='retriveCustomerOf(\""+c[i].num+"\")'>Customers</button>" +
    "<button class='btn btn-info' onclick=''>Prospects</button>"+
    "</div>";

var tabB = "" +
    '<div class="iw_field" style="border-bottom: 0px"><div class="iw_label">SALES VOLUME</div>'+
    '<div class="iw_data">$'+dollarFormat(c[i].statA)+'</div></div>' +
    '<table style="border-top: 1px solid #aaaaaa;"><tr><td>'+
    '<div class="iw_field"><div class="iw_label">GM</div><div id="" class="iw_data">$'+dollarFormat(c[i].statB)+'</div></div>'+
    '<div class="iw_field"><div class="iw_label">OPAT</div><div id="" class="iw_data">$'+dollarFormat(c[i].statC)+'</div></div>'+
    '<div class="iw_field"><div class="iw_label">ROI</div><div id="" class="iw_data">'+dollarFormat(c[i].statD)+'%</div></div>'+
    '</td><td>'+
    '<div class="iw_field"><div class="iw_label">GM RANK</div><div id="" class="iw_data">'+c[i].statE+'</div></div>'+
    '<div class="iw_field"><div class="iw_label">OPAT RANK</div><div id="" class="iw_data">'+c[i].statF+'</div></div>'+
    '<div class="iw_field"><div class="iw_label">ROI RANK</div><div id="" class="iw_data">'+c[i].statG+'</div></div>'+
    '</td></tr></table>';

var tabC = ""+
    '<div class="iw_field" style="border-bottom: 0px"><div class="iw_label">SERVICE REGION</div>'+
    '<div class="iw_data">'+c[i].area+'</div></div>' +
    '<table style="border-top: 1px solid #aaaaaa;"><tr><td>'+
    '<div class="iw_field"><div class="iw_label">PLACE 1</div><div id="" class="iw_data">$'+dollarFormat(c[i].p1)+'</div></div>'+
    '<div class="iw_field"><div class="iw_label">PLACE 2</div><div id="" class="iw_data">$'+dollarFormat(c[i].p2)+'</div></div>'+
    '</td><td>'+
    '<div class="iw_field"><div class="iw_label">PLACE 3</div><div id="" class="iw_data">$'+dollarFormat(c[i].p3)+'</div></div>'+
    '<div class="iw_field"><div class="iw_label">PLACE 4</div><div id="" class="iw_data">$'+dollarFormat(c[i].p4)+'</div></div>'+
    '</td></tr></table>';

var windowContent = "<div id='infowindow' class='company'>" +
    "<span class='header'>"+c[i].cName+" (#"+c[i].num+")</span>" +
    "<div class='tabs'>" +
    "<ul>" +
    "<li><a href='#tab_1' onclick='selectedTab = 0'><span>A</span></a></li>" +
    "<li><a href='#tab_2' onclick='selectedTab = 1'><span>B</span></a></li>" +
    "<li><a href='#tab_3' onclick='selectedTab = 2'><span>C</span></a></li>" +
    "</ul>" +
    "<div id='tab_1'>"+tabA+"</div>" +
    "<div id='tab_2'>"+tabB+"</div>" +
    "<div id='tab_3'>"+tabC+"</div>" +
    "</div>" +
    "<div style='text-align: right;'>"+
    "<button class='btn btn-primary' onclick='toggleRings(new google.maps.LatLng("+c[i].latitude+","+companies[i].longitude+"));'>Rings</button>" +
    "<button class='btn btn-primary' onclick='zoom("+c[i].latitude+", "+c[i].longitude+", 9)'>Zoom</button>"+
    "</div></div>";
```

This can't be the best practice to manage this code. Please save my sanity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check into a js template library. I've used [Embedded Javascript](http://embeddedjs.com/) and was happy with the results.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm semi new to this. I've developed a strong understanding of the fundamentals over the last few years but I'm now looking to learn the "easiest" way rather than the "proper" way.